# MUI makeStyles Props and logic to set multiple styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is a really simple on im sure, but i just cannot find an answer that works.

I am passing props to makeStyles like below.

```
const classes = useStyles({ isActive });
```

And then having to set up the properties like so.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: ({ isActive }) => isActive && "red,
    position: ({ isActive }) => isActive && "fixed",
    top: ({ genClaimsOpen, mileClaimsOpen }) => isActive && "20px",
  },
}));
```

What i would like to do (i have done similar in styled components), is group logic so that it is a lot cleaner to achieve more complex stylings)

Something like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    ({ isActive }) => isActive && (
        color: "red,
        position: "fixed",
        top: "20px"
    )
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find an answer, but I did a workaround using clsx package that allows me to do the logic in the className prop, and target specific classes depending on outcome.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Comment: Ok yes BUT is really really really distant from what you asked...

Comment: Thats why Im leaving this open to hopefully get an actual answer.